peewee: cannot find reference db_url
I am playing with peewee for my next project involving a database.
My first impression is rather good because it offers a good ORM and at the same time is not as big as SQLAlchemy.
Nevertheless I have a question for you.
Here is my piece of code:
from playhouse.db_url import connect
from peewee import Model, AutoField, TextField

database = connect('sqlite:///:memory:')
database.connect()

class Person(Model):
    id = AutoField()
    name = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = database

database.create_tables((Person,))


Person.create(name='Jim')
Person.create(name='John')

assert Person.select().count() == 2

database.close()

This code works perfectly. But PyCharm keeps on marking the first import statement as an error. It says it cannot find reference db_url, but when I run it either from the IDE or from the console it is working.
I have installed peewee  3.17.8 with pip on a venv with python 3.12.7
Since it works, I do not care much, but these red underlines are disturbing especially because they will make any code linters crazy.
Do you have an idea or a workaround for this issue?
For the moment, I have put  # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences on the line before, but I honestly do not like it.
Thanks!

No idea why you're seeing that, it's just a regular module in playhouse/. I'd suggest opening an issue w/the PyCharm people.
